# Haskell: Avoid using if for permutations?

Tags: haskell

I was trying to come up with a "one-liner" for generating permutations of a list in Haskell. This is what I have so far:

`perms xs = if length xs == 0 then [[]] else [x:ys | x <- xs, ys <- perms $ delete x xs]`

The problem is that I am having to use `if` which I don't like very much in Haskell. Is it possible to avoid using `if`, or a multi-part definition, or a case statement etc. and only "higher-order" functions (e.g. `foldr` etc.) to achieve this? (and also ideally keep it relatively small one-liner)

Comment: [Syntax in Functions - Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) should answer this. The actual strategy is pattern matching. I recommend you read the entire book, it's for free and online. The fact this function has multiple branches is enough to avoid a one-liner (the function as it is does not read well imo)

Comment: I don't want a multi-part or pattern-matching definition like I said. I am familiar enough with Haskell to not have to use that book.

Comment: What's wrong with using pattern matching or if expressions?

Comment: @mtahmed I am not sure about this, but I don't think you could encapsulate the recursion behind the `perms` function using folds (if that is what you are trying to do.) The reason being that `perms` needs to recurse on the whole list for each value in the list, as opposed to a fold which takes in a value from the list, one at a time and an accumulator. I of course could be wrong...

Comment: This might be possible with a more powerful recursion scheme. Folds on lists are catamorphisms but this problem is more like recursing through a tree than a list (the underlying data structure just happens to be a list). A recursion scheme that properly operated on the tree structure might be able to do this in a one liner, but I don't know of any library that provides an adequate function and implementing such a function is going to be far from a one-liner.

Comment: Thanks everyone!
@AaditMShah, nothing's wrong with it ... probably something "wrong" with a one-liner ... but this was just a curious question.

Comment: @acomar Category theory! Wonderful!

Answer (score 7):

If you find it satisfactory to just get rid of the `if` without any interesting changes to the function, `base-4.7.0.0` (bundled with GHC 7.8) includes [`bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Bool.html#v%3abool) in `Data.Bool`.

```
perms xs = bool [[]] [x:ys | x <- xs, ys <- perms $ delete x xs] $ not (null xs)
```

Comment: For earlier versions of base, `maybe` and `listToMaybe` can be abused to similar effect: `maybe [[]] (const [x:ys | x <- xs, ys <- perms $ delete x xs]) (listToMaybe xs)`

Answer (score 4):

I manage to implement this `perms` by using `foldr`, but it becomes more complex. It is hardly to believe this is what you are looking for:

```
perms xs = filter (\l -> length l == length xs) $ foldr step [[]] xs
    where step x acc = (map (x:) . perms $ delete x xs) ++ acc
```

Comment: What I was looking for was basically a way to "fold" this tree-like recursion somehow ... seems like no such construct exists ... so maybe I will try writing one for "educational purposes" ... time to category theory! :p

Answer (score 2):

```
[ghci] let perms1 xs = [x:ys | x <- xs, (not . null)  xs ,ys <- perms $ delete x xs]
[ghci] perms1 []
[]
[ghci] perms1 [1,2,3]
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```

Comment: Since list comprehensions are simply syntactic sugar for monadic computations, what you are looking for is the `guard` in front of the `delete` statement. You can also put it in front of the `x<- xs` statement. It comes to the same thing.

Comment: That's not quite enough for the OP, unfortunately. With his implementation, `perms [] = [[]]`.

Answer (score 0):

The higher function you need is the one that does the same thing as your `if` expression: check a given predicate, if true, then evaluate to expression1, else evaluate to expression2.

I didn't find this in the standard library, but this is the function you are looking for:

```
myBranchFunction :: t -> t -> [a] -> t
myBranchFunction e1 e2 xs = if length xs == 0 then e1 else e2
```

(you could generalize this further by having `length` be an argument to `myBranchFunction` if you would like.)

Then you could define `perms'` like so:

```
perms' :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
perms' xs = myBranchFunction [[]] [x:ys | x <- xs, ys <- perms $ delete x xs] xs
```

---

Note that all we are doing is moving the `if` expression out to another function. For this function, however, I think I would prefer not to try to fit it on one line and just use a `case` expression for readability.